# Editor Template Not Working for All Views In MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying out Editor Template
My Model Class is

```
public   class ResourceModel
    {

        public int ResourceId { get; set; }

        public string ResourceName { get; set; }

        public int CultureId { get; set; }

        public string CultureName { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public int CulturalResourceId { get; set; }

        public string ResourceValue { get; set; }

        public int ResourceAreaId { get; set; }
        public int ViewId { get; set; }

        public string WebView { get; set; }
        public int WebAreaId { get; set; }

        public string AreaName { get; set; }

        public string FinalResourceValue { get; set; }

        public List<ResourceModel> ListResourceCulture { get; set; }

    }
```

I have created a partial view for Editor Template and put that in a EditorTemplates folder inside Shared Folder  with name **ResourceModel.cshtml**.The Following is my Editor Template

```
 @model Mars.Model.ResourceModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CultureId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CulturalResourceId)


    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Language, new { @class="form-control"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResourceValue, new { @class="form-control"})
```

and I used @Html.EditorFor in the view page as

1.For the Create View

```
 @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.ListResourceCulture)
```

2.For the Edit View

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.ListResourceCulture)
```

These two views belong to same controller with different actions
The template works for the create page but the template doesn't works for the Edit page. The template does not get triggered.

Comment: Never use `Model => Model` (capital M) - you can get razor syntax errors depending on other code in your view (use `@Html.EditorFor(m  => m.ListResourceCulture)`). There is nothing in the code you have shown us suggesting it will not work. Are you sure your `ListResourceCulture` property is typeof `ResourceModel` in both cases?

Comment: yes it is same in both cases. Cant figure out what went wrong